# Optimize Rails update_all with conditions query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to update a value for a new attribute for 500k or even more existent records.

On migration, existent records will have that attribute value set to nil and I want it to set it to false.

First, I tried this in my seed file:

```
non_selected = Bonus.active.ranked.find(:all, conditions: { selected: nil })
non_selected.each { |b| b.update_attribute(:selected, false) }
```

but this was very slow. On benchmark measuring, this took ~140s for 10k bonus records.

Now, I changed to:

```
Bonus.active.ranked.update_all( "selected = false", "selected IS NULL" )
```

which takes 0.13s for 10k records.

But for 400k records, it will take 10s to update all.

How can I improve this query?

Comment: Rails 2? Anyway: your last statement translates to a single query. There is no quicker way imho.

Comment: yeah.. old app which has never been upgraded. Thanks, man. Couldn't figure out a better way, I was just concerned about this breaking the deploy to production.

Comment: what is the distribution of the selected column? if there are only a small percentage with selected=false you might want to consider creating an index on the selected column. Also make it NOT NULL and assign a default value.

Comment: what about changing the default value in your migration file to :false or :true as per your requirement and then do a migrate task through console ?

Comment: I'd post up the SQL to the postgres group, with some specs and maybe there's some tricks they know with postgres config to help. Indexes and not null are good, but maybe memory setting,things of that ilk